# Как указать несколько url при создании dataSource, чтобы приложение при аварии на первой базе отправляло запросы на вторую(дублирующую)?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, persistence

У меня есть приложение на spring-boot, запускается как обычный jar файл.
Так же использую обычный spring-boot datasource для работы с Oracle базой

На продакшене крутятся две базы, одна основная, а вторая - полностью дублирующая ее база на случай аварии.
Как в datasource указать несколько url, чтобы в случае недоступности основной базы, запросы стали пробрасываться на вторую резервную базу напрямую?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66142495

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Укажите параметры резервной БД в строке соединения с опцией [FAILOVER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netrf/local-naming-parameters-in-tns-ora-file.html#GUID-4A20F0A2-EDCD-4006-9177-2EA4B12D656D). В этом случае,  JDBC обработает сбой подключения к первичной БД и будет пытаться подключиться к резервной.

Создайте алиас для соединения в файле конфигурации tnsnames.ora:

```
DB_WITH_FAILOVER = (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = prima.host.ip_or_domain)(PORT = 1521))
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = secnd.host.ip_or_domain)(PORT = 1521))
        (FAILOVER = on)(LOAD_BALANCE = off)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME = service_name)
        (FAILOVER_MODE =
            (TYPE = select)(METHOD = preconnect)(RETRIES = 180)(DELAY = 10)
        )
    )
)
```

И укажите этот алиас в конфигурации подключения. Или, если пользоваться tnsnames.ora нежелательно, полное описание соединения, как показано выше, *в одну строку*:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@DB_WITH_FAILOVER

# OR -->

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS= [...])))
```

Подробнее читать о [Transparent Application Failover (TFA)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/transparent-application-failover.html#GUID-95B3215D-A988-4619-94BD-0C6F56B8F43C).