# Кластре,репликация,для Oracle 9i

Tags: база-данных, oracle, кластеризация, кластер

Делал только репликацию на mysql, имею только представление.

Есть сервер Windows Server 2003,  на нем крутится Oracle 9i.
Часто прилетают обновление по ИБ. ПРИХОДИТСЯ ПЕРЕГРУЖАТЬ.
нА КЛИЕНТАХ IP, НЕ МОГУ ПОМЕНЯТЬ ИЛИ ЗАДАТЬ dns ИМЯ,вшито в прожєкт.
Можно сделать как-то под одним ip две базы,что бы если что работала другая. Бо простоем на базе не бывает.

Comment: Посмотрите, может [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1242384/217579) поможет.